# MDX Change behavior from Excel 2010/Excel 365 (16.0.11328.20363)

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

We seen to have a change how excel perform some MDX stuff. We create a pivot from on external SSAS tabular with the measure defined as :

```
 PNLLEGACY1:=HASONEVALUE(PNLLEGACY[SubHeader]) ( DAX measure)
```

[The screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvE1R.png)

As you can see there is no value on ellipse when the `Collapse1` is expanded. When it’s collapsed, we got a value as you can see for example on `Collapse2`. If I expand `Collapse2`, the value will be blank on the line.

When I created the same on Excel 2010, I got a value when expanded. If I saved the file and refresh it with Office Excel 365 it works as expected (Same result as Excel 2010)

What is wrong? How can we get the same behavior as Excel 2010?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself on the issue; I hope that will help.

By default Total are not displayed so we need enable then!

To do that got to Pivottable / design / Subtotals

And choose Show all Subtotals at Top of Group

Kind regards